# Asp.Net C# DropDownList Selected Index Change Taking about 50 to 60 Sec

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

While working on asp.Net webforms. I realize and got many complains. dropdown selected Index is taking huge amount of time to bind another Dropdown on Selected Index Change did very simple thing to check but no luck.

```
 <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div>
                        <asp:Label Text="Category *" ID="LabelCompanyCategory" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="DropDownListCompanyCategory" runat="server"
                            AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                            Width="100%" CssClass="form-control" CausesValidation="False"
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceCategory" DataTextField="catDescription" DataValueField="CatId"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListCompanyCategory_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            EmptyMessage="Select Category">
                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="please select a category" Display="Dynamic"
                            ControlToValidate="DropDownListCompanyCategory" ForeColor="Red" ID="rfv2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceCategory" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:MainConnection %>' runat="server"
                            SelectCommand=" select CatId, Catdescription from dbo.category"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4" runat="server" id="DivActivity" visible="false">
                    <div>
                        <asp:Label Text="Activity *" ID="LabelCompanyActivity" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="DropDownListActivity" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Width="100%"
                            AppendDataBoundItems="false" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceActivity" EmptyMessage="Select Activity" CausesValidation="False"
                            DataTextField="activity" DataValueField="id">
                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="please select a Activity"
                            ControlToValidate="DropDownListActivity" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </div>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceActivity" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:MainConnection %>' runat="server"
                        SelectCommand="select activity, id from activity where catid=@CategoryId">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownListCompanyCategory" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                                DefaultValue="0" Name="CategoryId" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </div>
```

Back end Code:

```
 protected void DropDownListCompanyCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DivActivity.Visible = true;
    DropDownListActivity.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Have you checked query execution time given in `SqlDataSource`? If both queries has small execution time in SQL management tool, probably `ViewState` bloat becomes your issue.

Comment: Query is not Taking time... its Working Absolutely fine and no Complexity in Query At all.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik Components are amazingly fast, but you must configure them appropriately and use the RadAjaxManager.
Follow the example here: 
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/multiplecomboboxes/defaultcs.aspx

if the dataset is very large and the performance is still not good enough you must configure the loadOnDemand or revert to client side data binding.

Comment: Telerik Controls are working fine in total build. Even i have created Complete web on telerik COntrol they are working very fast. My DataSet Contains 1 to 20 Rows on each index. even some has only 1 row. but taking same time. some time exceeds from 60 seconds too. Applied many corrections but no luck